# Spring amqp @RabbitListener runtime type problems

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

So we are using the nice @RabbitHandler annotation in spring-amqp to create endpoints that resemble the coding style of RestControllers but work with Rabbit under the hood. Its all very nice and neat and it works great especially with dynamic resolution of method handlers based on signatures. However we are facing a bit of a controversy here. 
So imagine the following method

```
@RabbitHandler
public void handleEmailDto(EmailDto message) {
    System.out.println(message);
}
```

This will get handled by fromMessage method on the MessagingMessageConverter.java class. At a certain point down the chain the type information of the message will be required in order for the handler resolver to determine which method to call with the payload of the message, and what class to serialise the payload to. The thing is we are using MappingJackson2MessageConverter. Nevertheless, we need a populated ____TypeId____  prop of the message with the fully qualified name of the type of the class. Thats not a problem either. very well engineered and thought out.

The problem comes when this class is not on the classpath. This is actually a huge pain for us as we are working in a microservices environment and some of our services are completely decoupled. That is.. we do not want to have "common" artefact which holds  our data domain, just so we can use it at runtime in both the sender and receiver of the message. I have traced through the code, and I see how this hole type situation has been handled and why it is done the way it is.

However from architectural perspective, this is quite limiting... Does that mean that we definitely need to share code between microservices that are quite decoupled otherwise just to satisfy serialization/deserialization/method resolution logic ?

Maybe I am missing something or overlooking another way of doing it. If that is the case, I am certainly opened to suggestions. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: It sounds like you can try internal types from java lang itself instead of your customized types. Cause you do not share these classes across services. If we call this a schema, it should be same between services. Now that you do not share these classes, you should not use them neither. My seggestion is using internal types , such as `java.lang.Map` or `java.lang.List`. However, you need to do more specific job to get the properties there. By the way, wathever your are transfering from the network, you can put it in a map if they are not single primitive types. It's intelligent enough for you.

Comment: I don't quite understand the logic behind what you are saying. I am trying to consume some data and parse it into an object. When you hit a rest controller, you do not need to share the same type with the server, do you ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. What I'm saying is that you can read your data and deserialize them into a map instead of deserializing the data into an customized class type. For example, your remote service returns an serilized `A`(in json for example), which `A` stands for a customized class type(not single simple type, such as `long`), and then you can deserilize it into an map not a new `A` instance. At the end, you can get properties from this map. Have you got what I'm talking?

Comment: Yes I totally get what you are talking about and as a matter of fact we have considered that. However this is not viable for us. The point of this annotation is to make things easy. And when I say things, I mean method handling inference based on type information, etc. I do not see passing JsonNode objects or Strings on every "handler" method resulting in very readable and maintainable code. I do agree with you however. Its just not the solution we are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

1.6 has a [new feature](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_introduction.html#_json_messageconverter) where the argument type of the `@RabbitListener` is supplied to the JSON message converter which it can use instead of type id headers.

Unfortunately, this mechanism doesn't work with `@RabbitHandler`s because the hander method is (has to be) determined **after** the payload has been converted.

You don't need the source type on the class path, you can configure the converter to use a different type; see [this test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/annotation/EnableRabbitIntegrationTests.java#L385) for an example where we send a `Foo1` and receive a `Foo2`.

The listener is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/annotation/EnableRabbitIntegrationTests.java#L683) and the listener factory configuration with customized converter is [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/blob/master/spring-rabbit/src/test/java/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/annotation/EnableRabbitIntegrationTests.java#L906). See how the `idClassMapping` is set up to convert to the `Foo2` type.

Obviously the type has to be compatible with the source type, but it doesn't have to be the same class.